# Sql Server 2014 - Deep Recursive Parent-Child Self Join

Tags: sql, sql-server, recursion, recursive-query

I am trying to build a deep recursive self-join query. Having the table like:

```
Id | ParentId
1  | NULL
2  | 1
3  | 1
4  | 2
5  | 3
6  | 8
7  | 9
```

For Id 1 my query should be fetching 1,2,3,4,5 since they are either the children of 1 or children of the children of 1. In the given example 6 and 7 should not be included in the query result.

I tried using CTE but I am getting tons of duplicates:

```
WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT Id, ParentId
    FROM dbo.Table
    WHERE ParentId IS NULL
UNION ALL
    SELECT t.Id, t.ParentId
    FROM dbo.Table t
    INNER JOIN CTE c ON t.ParentId = c.Id
)
SELECT * FROM CTE
```

Ideas?

Comment: Your result will not include  6 and 7. what do you mean getting tons of duplicates?

Comment: https://ibb.co/TPxHXVj - sorry for link, no idea how else would I format it in comment. Thanks.

Comment: Do you need to be able to start at an arbitrary point in the hierarchy and traverse down the tree (like, in this example, would you expect to be able to start at Id = 2)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use `DISTINCT` to filter duplicate rows.

```
;WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT Id, ParentId
    FROM T
    WHERE ParentId IS NULL
UNION ALL
    SELECT t.Id, t.ParentId
    FROM T
    INNER JOIN CTE c ON t.ParentId = c.Id
)
SELECT DISTINCT Id, ParentId
FROM CTE
```

Comment: This answer is correct. I've spent some time looking into it and expected 10 nodes but in the meanwhile a buggy running script inserted 1000 new records under one of the nodes which I did not notice. The original query as in the question was giving the right output, The data was just incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following query with `CTE` where you can set parentId by `@parentID`:

```
DECLARE @parentID INT = 1
;WITH cte AS 
(
    SELECT 
    t.ID
    , t.ParentId
    FROM @table t
),
cteParent AS
(
    SELECT 
    t.ID
    , t.ParentId
    FROM @table t
    WHERE t.ParentId IN (SELECT t1.ID FROM @table t1 WHERE T1.ParentId = @parentID)
)

SELECT 
DISTINCT c1.ID
, c1.ParentId
FROM cte c1
INNER JOIN cte c2 ON c2.ParentId = c1.ID
UNION ALL 
SELECT * 
FROM cteParent
```

And the sample data:

```
DECLARE @table TABLE
(
    ID INT
    , ParentId INT
)

INSERT INTO @table
(
    ID,
    ParentId
)
VALUES
  (1, NULL )
, (2, 1 )

, (3, 1 )

, (4, 2 )

, (5, 3 )

, (6, 8 )

, (7, 9 )
```

OUTPUT:

```
ID  ParentId
1   NULL
2   1
3   1
4   2
5   3
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this sql script which result Parent Child Hierarchy

```
;WITH CTE(Id , ParentId)
AS
(
SELECT 1 , NULL  UNION ALL
SELECT 2 , 1     UNION ALL
SELECT 3 , 1     UNION ALL
SELECT 4 , 2     UNION ALL
SELECT 5 , 3     UNION ALL
SELECT 6 , 8     UNION ALL
SELECT 7 , 9
)
,Cte2
AS
(
    SELECT Id , 
          ParentId ,
         CAST('\'+ CAST(Id AS VARCHAR(MAX))AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS [Hierarchy]
    FROM CTE
    WHERE ParentId IS NULL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT c1.Id , 
          c1.ParentId ,
        [Hierarchy]+'\'+ CAST(c1.Id AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS [Hierarchy]
    FROM Cte2 c2
    INNER JOIN CTE c1
    ON  c1.ParentId = c2.Id
)
SELECT Id,
       RIGHT([Hierarchy],LEN([Hierarchy])-1) AS ParentChildHierarchy 
FROM Cte2

GO
```

Result

```
Id  ParentChildHierarchy
-------------------------
1    1
2    1\2
3    1\3
5    1\3\5
4    1\2\4
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see duplicates.

Your code returns the following on the data you provided:

```
Id  ParentId
1   
2   1
3   1
5   3
4   2
```

which is what you want.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=4234bdfdac2cee8e9505d05fa0f0079e) is a db<>fiddle.

Here is the code:

```
WITH t as (
      SELECT *
      FROM (VALUES (1, NULL), (2, 1), (3, 1), (4, 2), (5, 3), (6, 8), (7, 9)
           ) v(id, parentId)
    ),
    CTE AS (
    SELECT Id, ParentId
    FROM t
    WHERE ParentId IS NULL
UNION ALL
    SELECT t.Id, t.ParentId
    FROM t
    INNER JOIN CTE c ON t.ParentId = c.Id
)
SELECT *
FROM CTE;
```

If you are getting duplicates in your actual result set, then you presumably have duplicates in your original table.  I would recommend removing them *before* doing the recursive logic:

```
with t as (
      select distinct id, parentid
      from <your query>
     ),
     . . .
```

Then run the recursive logic.

Answer (score 0):

This query will help you

```
CREATE TABLE #table( ID INT, ParentId INT )

INSERT INTO #table(ID,ParentId)
VALUES (1, NULL ), (2, 1 ), (3, 1 ), (4, 2 ), (5, 3 ), (6, 8 ), (7, 9 )

;WITH CTE AS (
SELECT ID FROM #table WHERE PARENTID IS NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT T.ID FROM #table T  
INNER JOIN  #table T1 ON T.PARENTID =T1.ID 
) SELECT * FROM CTE
```